# How to configure PhpStorm to go through IIS url rewrite when debugging a file rather than loading the file directly

Tags: php, debugging, iis, ide, phpstorm

My apologies if this is not possible or if I'm asking the wrong question. I'm a little at a loss for even what to search for here.

I have my website configured so that pages are stored outside the root directory. To do this, all traffic is redirected through a controller.php page using url rewrite in IIS.

So the process looks like this: A user goes to `www.mywebsite/account/page.php`. No matter where the user went, IIS url rewrite redirects the user to `wwwroot/controller.php`. Controller.php then grabs the ORIGINAL_URI from an environment variable and then builds the page by including the actual page file from `includes/pages/[account/page.php]` outside the web root. The path is always the same within the `includes/pages/` folder as it would be in `wwwroot`. If it can't find a matching file there, it instead serves a 404 page.

I have debugging working fine with the chrome plugin by refreshing the page, but I was hoping there was a way to click the debug button within PhpStorm or click one of the browser buttons within PhpStorm and have it smart enough to load the page.

Is there a way to have PhpStorm look at the path of the current file I'm editing (`includes/pages/account/page.php`) and have it start in `wwwroot/account/page.php` and go through the url rewrite? Or perhaps is there a way to have it start in `wwwroot/controller.php` no matter what page I am debugging and pass it the path of the page (possibly in an environment variable)?

Comment: PhpStorm does not know how your framework finds your controllers/how you map URLs to files. But you can create Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Web Page" type and specify the URL you want to open/debug there. Once selected it can be clicked (Run or Debug) from any place in IDE (regardless of the file currently opened). P.S. What's wrong with Chrome/Firefox/etc Xdebug browser extension? I find it better than launching predefined URL from within the IDE. P.P.S. Just in case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I configured my dispatch via php-fpm (which maps at `not the www root`) ... and configured the php.ini for fpm to auto-start on my phpstorm idekey and port. When the php there starts executing, phpstorm will propose a dialog to map to a file. Voila ... all files in that directory structure will be mapped. I can break, step, etc. ps. The project must be open and listening for inbound connexions from xdebug.